# Do I need to explicitly use transactions with Django Rest Framework serializer updates?

Tags: django, transactions, django-rest-framework

According to http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations, in order to accept a nested serializer I need to create an `update` method.  None of the examples use transactions although they do modify multiple rows/tables.  Does the DRF somehow wrap things in transactions already, or should I explicitly put `transaction.atomic()` all over it?

Related PR:

- https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/pull/1787

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The related PR is unrelated to your question. PR is linked to the DRF specific exception handler that bypassed the default Django transaction scheme (https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/pull/1204#issuecomment-52712621).

DRF doesn't specifically wrap things in a transaction to leave the users free to choose whatever they want to.

Comment: Ok, so it's often appropriate to put a `@transaction.atomic` on the `def update(...)`, correct?

Comment: Well, I think and do so.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use Django's `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` database setting which will apply a transaction before the execution of each request and commit it if the request finishes successfully. More information here:

[Database transactions - Tying transactions to HTTP requests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#tying-transactions-to-http-requests)

Comment: watch out though, if your API has a lot of read operations, you might end up incurring unnecessary transaction overhead for these reads (transactions will be created even for read only operations with `ATOMIC_REQUESTS`)

Comment: Broken link:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#tying-transactions-to-http-requests

Answer (score 5):

first import transaction module from db, and then use the following

```
with transtaction.atomic():
    pass
```

This will ensure the atomicity and consistency of your data into database.