# Django rest framework avoid rollback on status!=200 responses

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, atomic, rollback

I have Django Rest Framework APIview used to add users into an application.
That APIview returns a status_code 200 when the user is created and a 400 if the user already exists on the application.
In any case the apiview should write into a 'events' table the action performed:

```
Events.objects.create(action='user-registration', result='ok/ko', otherinfo='whatever')
```

Seems DRF is designed to do a rollback to any database action whenever a **POST request** view returns a status code different to 200 in a response.

**It happens on POST requests but not in GET!!**

```
    class register_user(APIview):

      # This saves the event
      def get(self,request):
        Events.object.create(action='register-user',result='fail',otherinfo='forced fail')
        return JsonResponse(status=400, data={'status': 'ko','data':'forced fail'})

      # This does not saves the event
      def post(self,request):
        Events.object.create(action='register-user',result='fail',otherinfo='forced fail')
        return JsonResponse(status=400, data={'status': 'ko','data':'forced fail'})
```

How can I ensure the Event is persisted into the db even when the response is a status_code=400?

Comment: every other thing works fine except the database action?

Comment: Yes, everything else works. As you can see in the example I have reduced it to the minimum. A jsonresponse(status=200) works fine, but whatever else is rollbacked.
As far as I undertsand, DRF initiates a transaction to provide that behavior, but couldn't find how to overcome it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need to explicitly use transactions with Django Rest Framework serializer updates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34678784/do-i-need-to-explicitly-use-transactions-with-django-rest-framework-serializer-u)

Comment: I've rewritten the question to make it clear. It does works fine on GET requests, but not in POST. It is not related to atomic_requests (as far as I understand).

Answer (score 3):

[@Colegatron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1569247/colegatron) I know it's been a year but this saved me a ton of headache. Was indeed an issue with `django-reversion` version pre 4.x I believe. Updated to v5.0.1 and DB actions within an "unsuccessful" request are now persisted to the DB.

Answer (score 1):

If the `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` flag is set to True in your Django database settings, DRF will do a rollback in case of failed status codes. This PR introduces rollback functionality to DRF based on the `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` flag https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/pull/2887/files.

If you don't want this to happen, you can set the flag to `False` and can handle atomic requests explicitly.

Another approach can be to write a decorator which can set the `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` to `False` for the views. Django already has a decorator, but not sure if it works with DRF https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.non_atomic_requests

Comment: It is not related to atomic_requests (as far as I know). I've rewritten the question to make it clear. It does works fine on GET requests, but not in POST

Comment: The rollback happens because the write operations to the database i.e. POST request is being done under a transaction. This can be controlled with the ATOMIC_REQUESTS flag. Since in GET request there is no write operation in DB, it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Atul. I have been debugging and realized the django-reversion middleware has been tricking me this days. Not sure the reason, but whenever a requests status code is >= 400, whatever db action done inside the APIView is rolled back. Will have an issue on their github and in the meantime I'll have to stop using it.